# Angular - Form invalid with sub component

Tags: angular

I'm building a form. Some fields are required.

```html
<form #f = "ngForm">
  
 [...]
 <mat-form-field fxFlex = "10">
        <mat-label translate> location.code </mat-label>
        <input  matInput  type="text" required placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="location.code" name="code">
 </mat-form-field>

 [...]
 <inner-form-component [model]="location.innermodel"></inner-form-component>

</form>

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()" [disabled]="f.invalid"> 
       <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>
       {{ 'generic.submit' | translate }} 
</button>
```

The save button is automatically disabled if some required fields are not filled.
Unfortunately it doesn't work with fields inherited by the sub-component (inner-form-component) that adds other fields.

Is there a way to allow Angular to disabled the button with them too?

Comment: Hello, 
take a look at [this](https://netbasal.com/adding-integrated-validation-to-custom-form-controls-in-angular-dc55e49639ae)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475

You might be missing the viewProvider `ControlContainer` in your innner-component

Answer (score 0):

if you want a `FormGroup` to take into account a specific `ControlForm/FormGroup` you can use the `addControl` method, so in your `ngOnInit` you could have:

```
 f.addControl('location', location.innermodel)
```